# Camouflage grasshopper identification

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I came across the following grasshopper this afternoon while walking to my car. It was initially resting amongst some fallen tree leaves, but as I got closer to my car I must have startled it, as it then ran to the tree, and is also how I noticed it.

[image]

It was calm enough for me to temporarily hold it in a cut-in-half water bottle, and I was able to take a few more pictures, and record a [brief video](https://youtu.be/_cDN2UVJ3VQ). Afterwards, I released the grasshopper back into the grass and it promptly flew away. :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

When searching for its species, I was only able to find a dessert grasshopper, *Trimerotropis pallidipennis*, but I live in KY, and not out west, so I don't think that's it.

Can someone ID this for me please?

Location: Central KY, USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've found a Dissosteira carolina or carolina locust.
I'm not completely sure, but I think this is a male.
They are quite common in North America.

[image]

[idtools.org/id/grasshoppers/factsheet Dissosteira carolina](http://idtools.org/id/grasshoppers/factsheet.php?name=13171)
[uwyo.edu: Dissosteira carolina](http://www.uwyo.edu/entomology/grasshoppers/dica.htm)

Comment: Yes, [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Dissosteira-carolina-001.jpg) is it! Thank you.